# Memory issue with overload operator

Tags: c++

Suppose one has this code:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int foo) : foo(foo){}

private:
    int foo;

//overloaded operator +
public:
    MyClass operator+(MyClass &mc){
        MyClass c(mc.foo + foo);
        return c;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MyClass c1(10);
    MyClass c2(12);

    c2 = c1 + c2;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Where the operator + is overload such that it does not modify the object but create a new object and return it.

When `c2 = c1 + c2` is called, `c2` is bound with the new object, but the previous object bound with `c2` is not (or at least it seems to me) freed. I'm i right?

Since C++ has no a Garbage Collector, is this a problem?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Make it `MyClass operator+(MyClass const&mc) const` so that `c1 + c2 + c3` works and it's all good.

Comment: If you write the more correct `MyClass operator+(MyClass const & mc) const { return MyClass(mc.foo + foo); }`, you might be less confused.

Comment: Generally in C++, when it looks pretty, it's correct and Does The Right Thing. The key skill is to get it to look pretty :-)

Comment: C++ does not have a garbage collector because this works just fine without one.

Comment: He isn't confused by `operator+`; he is confused by `operator=`. "`c2` is bound with new object" indicates he's thinking in Java.

Comment: @Robᵩ I think you are really right :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When c2 = c1 + c2 is called, c2 is bound with the new object, but the previous object bound with c2 is not (or at least it seems to me) freed.

No, that's not what happens.

There is no "previous object bound with `c2`"; `c2` is not a reference to an object, it *is* the object. `c2`'s lifetime begins when it is declared and ends when it goes out of scope.

The assignment operator doesn't rebind `c2` (which would be meaningless -- `c2` isn't a java-style reference!), it assigns to it. Specifically, it invokes `c2.operator=(MyClass)` or `c2.operator=(const MyClass&)`. `c2` existed before the assignment, and *the same object* continues to exist after the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

The object is local. Only when memory is allocated dynamically(using new or malloc) we need to worry about explicitly freeing it. Local variables get destroyed once out of scope.

Comment: And it is passed back by value of course.... don't want the OP to think that the return value will be invalid.